# React-Native onKeyPress Android while having empty string

Tags: android, react-native, keyboard, textinput, onkeypress

I'm having an issue something.

I have have an app in which I have an Input that creates Chip/Tag. Basically, it's a textInput with a listing underneath and be clicking on a item in the list, it remove the text and add a chip juste before it.

What I'm trying to do is to be able to delete the last Chip by using backspace in the TextInput ONLY WHEN there are no value to it.

So it would be a simple way to delete the chip without having to remove them by clicking on a little x on them. (Basically how the Tags on Stack Overflow works)

I know that since RN-0.53, they added support to the `onKeyPress` props of the TextInput. However, it does not trigger when making a backspace on an empty value (since the value technically didn't change)

Anyone would have an idea to catch the Backspace action when the textInput is empty? Or possibly a workaround?

Thanks!